# How to Handle _www User Not Having Access to .hg Folder?

Tags: php, version-control, mercurial, permissions, bitbucket

I have a **BitBucket** account, and it will trigger a script on my sever that will pull and update the live server when a push is made. The trigger works, and after having a lot of troubles getting the `_www` user to trust the hgrc or whatever (I did get that working), it's actually doing the command.

The problem is I get an error about not being able to lock the folder, which means that my `_www` user doesn't have permission to the .hg folder.

What's a good way to approach this? I don't want to make the .hg folder 0777. I could put `_www` in the same group as my user (which I believe it is) and give the group rw (what is that, 0775?). Would that be acceptable, or are there other security implications I might be missing, or a better way to handle this.

I was I could run the command with my user. And maybe I can. **BitBucket** is using a POST service to post to my server and I do the command via PHP's `shell_exec()` (it only runs the command if the request came from BitBucket's IP).

**[Update]** I went ahead and tried setting the permissions to 0775, and it still didn't work  (`_www` isn't in the same group as my user). Same error, which is:

> abort: could not lock repository /path/to/local/repo: Permission denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea with the groups stuff.  You need to:

- make sure the www user is in the same group as the group that owns *everything* in the .hg directory
- make sure *everything* in the .hg directory is write-able by group (`chmod -R g+w .hg`)

If any other users besides www will be pushing/pulling/updating in that repo then you'll also want to use the sticky-group-bit to make sure that newly created files and directory have the same group ownership as the `.hg` directory itself.:

```
find .hg -type d | xargs chmod g+s
```

Comment: Groups still mess me up. The group that the `_www` user is in is `_www`. As root, what *exactly* do I run to make `.hg` recognize now and in the future the `_www` group as ok? I've never see `g` nor `S`, but like I said, I don't really ever have to mess with groups.

Comment: You don't make .hg recognize _www is okay.  You put the _www user into whatever group is the "group owner" of the .hg directory.  Users can be in multiple groups and you add them with `usermod`.  What is the current group ownership of your `.hg` directory?

Comment: Owner is `cameron` and owner group is `staff` since I guess I was the one that `hg clone`d the repo.

Comment: Capital `S` gave me an error, but from what I could find online, `s` is what I wanted, so I used that, and I think things are working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: err, I had to do all of that stuff to the entire repo, and not just `.hg`

Comment: Yeah, if you have a working directory you need to do it in the hgroot.  Usually the web server accessible repos don't have working directories, but if you're using mercurial as a deploy tool that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your first paragraph is not entirely clear, but have you tried changing the `.hgrc` file on the live server, adding:

```
[trusted]
users = _www
groups = _www
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried clarifying my first paragraph. It doesn't seem to be a trust issue (anymore), but a permissions issue. Which I COULD fix by just making everything 0777, but I don't want to do that.